# Println MongoDB Record to Console from lift

Tags: mongodb, console, lift, println

I insert a Record into a MongoDB

```
var test = Entry.createRecord
.name("Williams")
.nr("1")
.save
```

How can I println these document via query to commandline console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends if you're mongo-java-driver apis, or use the lift-json DSL to construct your queries.

For JSON, something like.

```
Entry.findAll(("name" -> "Williams"))
```

For API

```
val qry = QueryBuilder.start("name").is("Williams").get
Entry.findAll(qry)
```